# React Native: Binding Template

Tags: react-native, templates

Is there any way to bind TextChangeable to React Component?

```
render() {
    const TextChangeable = `
    <Text style={styles.descText}>
      All reports size is
        <Text style={styles.downloadSize}>
            38 MB
        </Text>
    </Text>
    `
    return <View>
      {TextChangeable}
    </View>
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @kishan I want to make the text "38 MB" in bold style. and the entire sentence "All reports size is 38 MB" can be translated into arabic language

Comment: @Phaoga54 How you are doing translation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const TextChangeable = () => {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.descText}>
      All reports size is
        <Text style={styles.downloadSize}>
            38 MB
        </Text>
    </Text>
  );
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextChangeable />
      </View>
   );
}
```